# How much does the reputation of the institute you did your masters from matter for PhD admissions (Computer Science)?

Tags: graduate-admissions, computer-science

I am planning to do a thesis based MS in CS from Arizona State University. I want to know what impact (positive or negative) ASU's tag would have for PhD admissions into top universities such as Stanford.

Comment: Ask the department what their MS students do after graduation. But, even then, any name recognition does not go very far relative to your academic and research record.

Answer (score 2):

ASU has a good reputation generally, but, as is the case with most universities, it is your record and not the history of the institution that will be dominant in further admissions. If you are a top student at ASU and get stellar recommendations you will be in the running. If you are a C student at MIT with mediocre recommendations you probably won't be.

But, in the US, you can apply to doctoral programs in most fields, including CS direct from a bachelors program. You don't need an MS first. But it will still depend on your current record. How well can you present yourself on all relevant criteria.

But, wherever you go, get noticed for your excellence and your hard work. Make it clear to advisors that you have potential. That, and not the name of the institute, will be decisive.

In my personal case, I got noticed because I asked a lot of questions in class. It turned out that they were questions that other students also had, but didn't ask. I later learned from my peers that they thought I was terrifically smart because I asked all those questions. My mom, on the other hand, thought I was a pain in the butt for all my (constant) questions. Ask and ye shall learn.